# I am getting SvnRepositoryIOException: OPTIONS while trying to access the repository using sharpsvn in asp.net 3.5

Tags: sharpsvn

OPTIONS of 'http://websvn.tigris.org/svn/websvn': Could not resolve hostname `websvn.tigris.org': No such host is known.
(http://websvn.tigris.org)

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that your DNS is not setup directly. Try `ping websvn.tigris.org` on the server that you use for running your code.